# Implementation of flatMap() for State transition

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, state-monad, flatmap

Exercise 6.8, Chiusano and Bjarnason, *Functional Programming in Scala*, p. 87 asks how one might implement flatMap() for the following trait:

```
trait RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG)
}

type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)
```

The answer key gives the following solution:

```
def flatMap[A,B](f: Rand[A])(g: A => Rand[B]): Rand[B] =
rng => {
  val (a, r1) = f(rng)
  g(a)(r1) // We pass the new state along
}
```

Stackoverflow provides many answers to flatMap()/monad questions, but none which for me answered my questions regarding the next to last line of code.

I do not understand the syntax of the line

```
g(a)(r1)
```

(1) I do not understand how g(a)(r1) evaluates. What syntactic function is served by (r1)? The line does not exemplify currying, I do not believe, since g takes only one argument: A. 
(2) If g(a) will already return the type Rand[B], then why does not the line end here? 
(3) what is the relation between the Rand[B] returned by g(a) and the second set of parentheses: (r1)? 
(4) if the return type of this implementation of flatMap() is Rand[B], which is equal to RNG => (A, RNG), how are the enclosing parentheses to the right of the arrow generated? If I had to guess I would say they are generated by the evaluation, (r1), but I do not really understand this code given my questions 1 through 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that we're calling `f` and `g` inside a new anonymous function, as indicated by the line

```
rng => { ... }
```

`g` returns a `Rand[B]` when given an `A`, so `g(a)` evaluates to a function from `RNG` to `(A, RNG)`.

So `g(a)` returns a function expecting an `RNG` as its argument, we can then call this with our `r1`, which is of type `RNG`.

The result of the call is `(B, RNG)`. Now since the `flatMap` signature expects you to return a `Rand[B]` which is the same as `RNG => (B, RNG)` and we return `(B, RNG)` inside our function, it exactly matches the signature.

Comment: Thanks, Luka, this is great. Makes perfect sense. The key knowledge for me is to learn that (r1) indeed represents the call on the function returned by g(a). I guess it is like curry syntax:  f[A,B,C](a)(b) : a => (b => c), in reverse.