# Scala - State Actions - FP in Scala Exercises Chapter 6 - Evaluation of FlatMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm having a hard time breaking down the evaluation in Section 6.9 when implementing map2 in terms of FlatMap from Functional Programming in Scala.

So map2 looks like

```
def map2[A,B,C](ra: Rand[A], rb: Rand[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Rand[C] = {
  rng => {
    val (a, r1) = ra(rng)
    val (b, r2) = rb(r1)
    (f(a, b), r2)
  }
}
```

and flatMap looks like:

```
def flatMap[A, B](f: Rand[A])(g: A => Rand[B]): Rand[B] = rng => {
  val (a, r1) = f(rng)
  g(a)(r1)
}
```

I beat my head against a wall for a few days and could not figure out how to do map2 in terms of flatmap (map, oddly, came to me right away).

Looking at a solution to map2 in terms of flatMap from the solutions repo:

```
def _map2[A,B,C](s1: Rand[A], s2: Rand[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Rand[C] = {
  flatMap(s1)(a => flatMap(s2)(b => unit(f(a,b))))
}
```

But I'm confused on how this function expands in terms of evaluation --I can't seem to write out the evaluation by hand.  I don't see how I have the second f: (A, B) => C that gets returned to the outer flatMap.

I suppose this is the next question after this post: [Implementation of flatMap() for State transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398122/implementation-of-flatmap-for-state-transition) !

Comment: For `Rand` to work, the input seed must be "incremented" for each pseudo-random value generated.  If the same seed is used twice to pull two `X`s out of a `Rand[X]`, those two `X`s will be the same.  The "effect" of the `Rand` monad is "incrementing" this seed for you.  `map2` takes three arguments: `Rand[A]`, `Rand[B]` and a function `(A,B) -> C`.  `map2` must generate the pseudo-random `A` and `B` before the function `(A,B)->C` can be applied.  `map2` generates the `A`, increments the seed, then generates the `B`, increments the seed, and then applies the function `(A, B) -> C`.

Comment: 100%.  It's clear in the original implementation of map2.  I don't see how scala expands the `_map2` function that uses flatMap.  I suppose this is more of a question of how Scala would evaluate the above.  If I go inside out, it looks like f(a,b) is expanded first but it's not clear since a and b have not been generated yet.  It's not clear to me which of the two  `flatMap` even is the first to increment the seed and pass the state.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now, thanks.  Take a look at these: https://github.com/peterbecich/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/state/State.scala#L20-L27   and  https://github.com/peterbecich/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/state/State.scala#L181-L200

Comment: It's a bogus implementation of the `RNG` trait that only increments the seed by one.

Comment: Ah.  AH!  Thank you.  This was the breakthrough I've been trying to see all day.

Comment: Cool!  Sure thing!